# Current Monitor output equation

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog

I was trying to get the output equation of the below current monitor.

The circuit I obtained from TI document [AN-31](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla140d/snla140d.pdf?ts=1699508050488&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsitesearch%252Fen-us%252Fdocs%252Funiversalsearch.tsp%253FlangPref%253Den-US%2526searchTerm%253Dan-31%2526nr%253D99).Amplifier circuit collection page no 35.

I got the correct equation.

May I know any other way to solve this problem.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

op-amp  both inputs have the same voltage.

```
V(R2) = V(R1)
```

Therefore current in R2 is some multiple of current in R1

```
I(R2) = I(R1)*R1/R2
```

R3 is in series with R2 (and nothing can inject current between them) therefore same current

```
I(R3) = I(R2)
```

compute voltage drop of R3

```
V(R3) = I(R3)*R3

V(R3) = I(R1)*R1*R3/R2
```

But I think that's essentially the same as your answer.